# JSON schema: Selecting a single value from a list should be valid

Tags: json, validation, schema

For the validation of an input field I want to create a JSON schema.
It is about the selection of a time zone. All possible time zones are to be stored in the schema. My problem is that if several time zones are under one continent, the selection of a single time zone is invalid.

Shortened SCHEMA:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Continents Timezones",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "continents": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "continent": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "timezones": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "timezone": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "utc_offset": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "dst_offset": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "timezone",
                "utc_offset",
                "dst_offset"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "continent",
          "timezones"
        ],
        "enum": [
          {
            "continent": "Africa",
            "timezones": [
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Abidjan",
                "utc_offset": "+00:00",
                "dst_offset": "+00:00"
              },
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Accra",
                "utc_offset": "+00:00",
                "dst_offset": "+00:00"
              },
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Addis_Ababa",
                "utc_offset": "+03:00",
                "dst_offset": "+03:00"
              },
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Algiers",
                "utc_offset": "+01:00",
                "dst_offset": "+01:00"
              },
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Asmara",
                "utc_offset": "+03:00",
                "dst_offset": "+03:00"
              },
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Bamako",
                "utc_offset": "+00:00",
                "dst_offset": "+00:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "continent": "UTC",
            "timezones": [
              {
                "timezone": "UTC",
                "utc_offset": "+00:00",
                "dst_offset": "+00:00"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "continents"
  ]
}
```

the following JSON should be valid:

```json
{
  "continents": [
    {
            "continent": "Africa",
            "timezones": [
              {
                "timezone": "Africa/Abidjan",
                "utc_offset": "+00:00",
                "dst_offset": "+00:00"
              }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If there is only one time zone under the continent, as in the case of UTC, the JSON is valid.